# Is there any way to write code or use <iframe> tag to display service related content in .JPEG / .PNG images

Tags: visualforce, html

When the end user is viewing downloaded images from web, at that point, the client wants to display his service related information in bottom of the image (if internet connection is available). Is it there any way to display content in .JPEG / PNG images when the end user opens it from his machine.

Comment: Could you provide some example values of what the "service related content" would be? Do you mean things like the clients IP address that sent the request to Salesforce?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Daniel, I have designed Visual force page, it shows the company service related information. Users are downloading images form my website at that point of time I would like to include my Visualforce link into the JPEG / PNG image. When user open the images from his computer / mobile they need to see our company service list.